# Reference to Lebesgue space on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a reference to the Lebesgue spaces $L^p(M)$, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold. This question is motivated by $L^p(\partial\Omega)$ where $\partial\Omega$ is the boundary of a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. That is, $\partial\Omega$ is considered as a compact Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The space $L^p(M)$ is defined for any measurable space $M$ i.e. any space equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets. In particular, if $M$ is a topological space (like a manifold) the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra is taken implicitly. A good introductory book to Lebesgue integration is 'Measure, Integral and Probability' by Capinski.

Comment: @pg_star What? $L^p$ is defined on a _measure space_, not a measurable space.

Comment: If $M$ is nothing but a manifold do you have some reason to think there _is_ a standard notion of $L^p(M)$? We'd need a canonical measure; I can't imagine where that would come from. $L^p_{loc}(M)$ can probably be defined in a  reasonable way...

Comment: I have seen the notion $L^p(M)$ , for a Riemannian manifold $M$.

Comment: A Riemannian manifold is much more than just a manifold! (The metric allows one to construct that canonical measure...)

Comment: There's an introductory text I have not read on the laplacian on a. Riemannian mfld which contains some L^2 theory, "The Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold: an introduction to analysis on manifolds"

Comment: Forgot to mention, author: Steven Rosenberg

Comment: A Riemannian metric gives a canonical volume form on a Riemannian manifold, which induces a measure by going through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem.

Comment: I've also seen it defined as the closure of $C^\infty(M)$ under the $L^p$ norm. I'm wondering if anyone knows whether these are obviously the same or not?

Comment: @Keshav from glancing through the first few bits of the above book i mentioned, its not usually this closure unless $M$ is compact

Comment: Ah that's right.